# How do I make Git commands print all output immediately and not wait for me to hit 'q'?

Tags: git, shell

If I enter `git log; git push`, I will get a very long log output that I must exit by hitting 'q' before the following command is executed. `git status` does not behave in this way; if I've changed a thousand files it still prints the whole output without waiting.

How do I make my Git command, for example `git log` or `git config --list`, print everything like `git status` does?

Comment: `git log` by itself does not request you to print _q_. You could turn off the pager (as ElpieKay suggested), or specify `cat` as a pager (`PAGER=cat git log; git push`). Of course the real question is, why you want to produce the whole output, if you then don't want to see it. Hence, perhaps a more reasonable approach would be to do something like `git log|head; git push`, which shows just the top lines of the log.

Comment: @user1934428 The specific application I have in mind is a script for my team to set a bunch of config settings and aliases; I want to list global config before and after for reference.

Comment: The discussions for `git log` should apply equally well to `git config`.

Comment: @user1934428 I'm printing it for reference; it is not desirable for it to halt execution or for 'q' to shorten the output.

Comment: For reference .... So how about doing then a `git config|tail -n ${LINES:-24}`? This ensures that enough of the git output is printed to fill the screen, but does not block.

Comment: @user1934428 The point is to have the whole output available in case you need to see what values you overwrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because a pager (`less` by default) is working. You have several options to disable the pager.

[git -P <cmd>](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--P)

```
git -P log
git --no-pager log
```

[$GIT_PAGER, core.pager, $PAGER](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corepager)

```
# for once
git -c core.pager= log
GIT_PAGER= git log
PAGER= git log

# always
git config --global core.pager ""
git log
```

[pager.<cmd>](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pagerltcmdgt)

```
# To disable the pager for git log only
git -c pager.log=false log

# always
git config --global pager.log false
git log
```

You can also specify a tool as the pager, like `cat` to emit all the output.

```
git -c core.pager=cat log
GIT_PAGER=cat git log
PAGER=cat git log
git -c pager.log=cat log
```

Comment: You can also configure `less` to not require you to explicitly quit when you reach the end of the file. For global configuration, `export LESS=-<your options here>` in your shell's startup file; for Git specifically, try something like `alias git='LESS=-qMX \git'` or a function with the same semantics.

Comment: Thank you! This will do for my particular purpose, but suppose I wanted this to work with `git diff` where I use `core.pager 'less -x1,5'` to make tabs interchangeable with 4 spaces. Can it be done?

Comment: @H.v.M. Try `git -c pager.diff="less -x1,5" diff`. If it works, run `git config --global pager.diff "less -x1,5"` to write the variable and its value to the configuration file, so that `git diff` will call `less -x1,5` as its pager.

Comment: @ElpieKay Yes that works, although I wondered rather if I could get both effects at the same time: print all and show tabs as 4 spaces. I found that `tabs -c3` will work and persists for the current git bash session. `tabs -c3; git -P diff; tabs` if you want to reset it afterwards.

Comment: @tripleee I wrote `LESS=-qMX git log` and it does require me to hit 'q' to exit. It also screws up colors; for example a colored hash `8705bc7` becomes `ESC[33m8705bc7ESC[m`.

Comment: @H.v.M. To get both effects, I think you can look into [git diff driver](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_an_external_diff_driver). Use the driver to deal with tabs. But so far, I haven't really used it yet.

Comment: Those are just the flags I routinely use; try adding `r` for the colors and `e` or `E` for avoiding to need to press `q`. The manual page is your friend.

Comment: @H.v.M. I missed a simple solution to get both effects, `git -c pager.diff="less -x1,5" -P diff`.

Comment: @ElpieKay Doesn't work - it just first sets and then unsets the pager, so it's the same as `-P`.

Comment: @tripleee I checked the manual page and I didn't find any setting that prints all output immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Simply unset `PAGER` temporarily shell's variable:

```
PAGER= git log
```

or

```
git log | cat
```

Comment: Or `git --no-pager log`.